# Go Memory Profiling

Tags: memory, go

It is already the second time that I notice one of my Go program taking alot of memory (much more that I would expect) and that I do not understand why, so here I am.
I decided to profile the memory with pprof and the result of the top5 pprof memory profiling is as such:

```
1140.28MB of 1169.97MB total (97.46%)
Dropped 61 nodes (cum <= 5.85MB)
Showing top 5 nodes out of 15 (cum >= 33.89MB)
```

My problem is the following. In the profile we see that the program consumed roughly 1.2GB of memory (which is affordable for what I am doing, parsing and indexing logs). However, when I do a "top command" and look at the resident memory used by my program, it is rather around 10GB to 11GB of memory taken by the program which is quite a huge difference with the memory profiling.

So where are those Gigs of memory that I don't see in the profile ?
And why ?
How to troubleshout ?

Thanks by advance,

Comment: What's are the `runtime.MemStats` at this point? (also shown in `/debug/pprof/heap` if you're using the http/pprof hook)

Comment: I have the same issue now. Is there any description? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that extra memory usage is from the file system, esp. since you are probably scanning over a lot of disk.

See: http://www.linuxatemyram.com/